# Sending GCM Notification to 100 000 users with a PHP script

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a GCM Notifications based app,everytime a new user installs app its GCM registration id is stored on the php server's mysql database , now I have written a script to send notification to all registered users as follows

```
<?php

//------------------------------
// Payload data you want to send 
// to Android device (will be
// accessible via intent extras)
//------------------------------


//------------------------------
// The recipient registration IDs
// that will receive the push
// (Should be stored in your DB)
// 
// Read about it here:
// http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/
//------------------------------

if(isset($_GET['message'])) 
{

    $msg = $_GET['message'];
    $data = array("price" => $msg);
    $ids = array();
    require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/db_connect.php';;
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT gcm_regid FROM gcm_users");



    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $ids[] = $row['gcm_regid'];
    }

//$ids = array( 'abc', 'def' );

//------------------------------
// Call our custom GCM function
//------------------------------


//------------------------------
// Define custom GCM function
//------------------------------

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
    //------------------------------
    // Replace with real GCM API 
    // key from Google APIs Console
    // 
    // https://code.google.com/apis/console/
    //------------------------------

    $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    //------------------------------
    // Define URL to GCM endpoint
    //------------------------------

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    //------------------------------
    // Set GCM post variables
    // (Device IDs and push payload)
    //------------------------------

    $post = array(
                    'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                    'data'              => $data,
                    );

    //------------------------------
    // Set CURL request headers
    // (Authentication and type)
    //------------------------------

    $headers = array( 
                        'Authorization: key='. $apiKey,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

    //------------------------------
    // Initialize curl handle
    //------------------------------

    $ch = curl_init();

    //------------------------------
    // Set URL to GCM endpoint
    //------------------------------

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    //------------------------------
    // Set request method to POST
    //------------------------------

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    //------------------------------
    // Set our custom headers
    //------------------------------

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    //------------------------------
    // Get the response back as 
    // string instead of printing it
    //------------------------------

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    //------------------------------
    // Set post data as JSON
    //------------------------------

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

    //------------------------------
    // Actually send the push!
    //------------------------------

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    //------------------------------
    // Error? Display it!
    //------------------------------

    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    //------------------------------
    // Close curl handle
    //------------------------------

    curl_close( $ch );

    //------------------------------
    // Debug GCM response
    //------------------------------

    echo $result;
}
sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );

}
?>
```

My worry is that when the user base will be huge then the script might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will fail if you send more than 1000 registration IDs in the same request to GCM. You must make sure that each request contains at most 1000 registration IDs.

> **registration_ids**  A string array with the list of devices
>   (registration IDs) receiving the message. It must contain at least 1
>   and **at most 1000 registration IDs**. To send a multicast message, you
>   must use JSON. For sending a single message to a single device, you
>   could use a JSON object with just 1 registration id, or plain text
>   (see below). A request must include a recipient—this can be either a
>   registration ID, an array of registration IDs, or a notification_key.
>   Required.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html))